# Keyboard is not shown once I tap on UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

When I tap on a `UITableViewCell` in tableview it displays a `UIPickerView`. I select that row & set row to `UITextField`.

But when I tap the same textfield for editing then the keyboard is not shown.

Comment: If you are using simulator, press cmd+k buttons.

Comment: I am trying it but not work.actually problem is only shown that keyboard color as gray but keyboard not shown

Comment: If i am selecting cell first time then it display keyboard but when i am select pickerview & after if i want to edit textfield then that time not shown keyboard

Comment: check any other view is hiding the keyboard??? after selecting picker, just make [textfield becomeFirstResponder].